# Why doesn't command line echo in Kubernetes Pod container show in logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-pod

Consider this Kubernetes Pod:

```
# pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testing123
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testing123
    image: busybox:latest
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo "Hello, Kubernetes!" && sleep 3600']
```

If I deploy this Pod and run `logs` I see this:

```
$ kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
$ k logs testing123           
Hello, Kubernetes!
```

So far, so good. I now "login" to the Pod and run an echo command:

```
$ k exec -ti testing123 -- ash
/ # echo "Run after logging in."
Run after logging in.
/ # exit
$ k logs testing123           
Hello, Kubernetes!
$
```

Why didn't `Run after logging in.` appear in the logs output of the Pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers logs are captured from their command line / entrypoint stdout and stderr.

When you enter a container (kubectl exec), you spawn a new process, with its own stdin/stdout/stderr.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the container to send all new process's stdout to the entrypoint's stdout?

Comment: not that I know of. outside of kubectl exec, processes may fork() and start child processes, whose stdout may not be suitable for logging. Regarding kubectl exec specifically: I don't know of any way to log what's going on when someone enters a container. Maybe you could setup some profile for your shell, with some `exec 1>>/proc/1/fd/1` (? un-tested / redirect everything to the stdout of PID 1, which should be your entrypoint), Or just remove shells from container images.

Comment: While we should keep in mind: PID 1 would be your entrypoint most of the times ... Unless  your pod is sharing the host PID namespace ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces ). So really, there's no definitive answer for that one, AFAIK.